# Callbacks for cordova plugin in background

Tags: cordova, background, callback

We have native SDKs for iOS and Android, and improving a plugin for cordova that integrates both SDKs. 
SDK basically detects bluetooth beacons, geofences and receives push notifications, the main problem we are facing, is that in native code we can deliver callbacks in the background to the developer's app as soon as they happen, so it can perform actions immediately in their code, however in cordova this does not seem to be possible.

As far as I've understood, developers code (JavaScript) depends on a webview in order to run, but this webview **is not  instantiated** if, for example, App is launched by the OS because an `Intent` (Android) or a location event such `didEnterRegion` (iOS). Is that correct?

If the above information is correct, does Cordova framework "collect" the callbacks and deliver them all together when the webview is instantiated (e.g. app goes to foreground)?

Unfortunately, I haven't be able to find better documentation regarding this topic.

Comment: I have never tryed beacons, but they are supposed to wake the app, so you shouldn't have problems with that. Push notifications are handled by the system, not by the app, if the user touchs the notification the app wakes and you receive the notification data without problems.

Comment: @jcesarmobile All the hard work is already done with the native SDKs. The question is not how to implement this features in cordova, but how to deliver callbacks to the cordova JavaScript code when the app is not in foreground.

Comment: as I said on the previous message, beacons are supposed to wake up the app, so the app isn't in background, it's in foreground

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thank your for your answer. When you receive a location update from a bluetooth beacon in iOS, the OS will wake up the app in the background, but it does not mean a view will be instantiated. If a cordova web view is not instantiated, the developer's code won't be able to receive callbacks **even if the app is running in the background**. And that is why I am asking the question above.

Comment: but have you tried? if the webview isn't instantiated no javascript will be executed, but the plugin code is native and will be executed. Take a look into the ibeacon plugin https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon. You can try a sample project https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-proximity-quickstart

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes finally I have decided to just try it out and answer this question with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but maybe useful for others.

There is a great plugin to do just this; I'm not associated with the plugin in anyway but I have used it to solve this exact problem for push notifications. The app loads in the background and the javascript code executes as normal (deviceReady callbacks, etc.), not tested on iOS yet: -

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugin background won't listen to many of the events...